# EnsureUser returns none existing users using ldapprovider

Tags: 2010, powershell, forms-authentication, ldap

I'm writing a PowerShell script that adds users to a SharePoint site. To check if the user exists I'm calling the EnsureUser. But my issue is that the when calling this method with a ldap membership provider(Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider) (i:0#.f|ldapmembership|username) it always returns a user even the user do not exists in Active Directory. So I'm able to add uses that do not exists.

Comment: Are you using AD Groups?

Comment: Yes we are using the LdapRoleProvider for groups, but this script is adding users.

Comment: Are you checking the user like this? SPWeb.EnsureUser(i:0#.f|ad_membership|user) (A code sample from you might help in this case)

Comment: Yes. $web = Get-SpWeb <url>;$user = $web.EnsureUser(i:0#.f|ldapmembership|username); #No exception even user does not exists i source.

Comment: Are the AD groups nested at all? Nested groups can't be read for permissions by all functions.

Comment: Ok, no I do not think there are any nested groups.

Comment: I have looked through the function and for what could be causing this, and all I can see is that the user information that it is looking up isn't being resolved properly. Do the accounts have email addresses? I recently found out that this is the preferred way from the code of resolving user accounts.